# Mention du post-scriptum dans un courrier électronique

Tags: typographie, abréviations, correspondance

[L'entrée post-scriptum de la Wikipédia francophone](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-scriptum) mentionne différentes typographies possibles pour le post-scriptum :

- P.-S.
- PS
- P. S.
- p.-s.

Y'a-t-il un consensus sur le meilleur choix à faire ? Ou alors est-ce que ça dépend du cadre (informel ou non) ? Certaines formes sont-elles à bannir ?

N'a-t-il pas aussi une fonction de surlignage (en plus de celui l'oubli) ? 
Peut-il être utilisé dans ce sens : pour mettre de l'emphase ? Cela pourrait peut-être en justifier l'usage dans un courriel.

Je me suis posé la question étant donné que le correcteur orthographique de Thunderbird n'accepte pas « PS », mais il est vrai qu'il n'accepte pas P.-S. non plus. Au contraire, le correcteur de Google Chrome accepte toutes les formes mentionnées, mais souligne « scriptum » dans « post-scriptum ».

Comment: Je ne me prononcerai pas sur l'orthographe correcte de l'abbréviation de post-scriptum. Mais il reste pertinent de dire que l'utilisation d'un post-scriptum *dans un courrier électronique* (email) est **injustifiée**. La raison d'être du post-scriptum est la suivante: permettre d'ajouter un élément oublié, **APRÈS** avoir terminé la rédaction. Il était en effet dommage d'avoir à recopier toute une lettre de 3 pages parce qu'on a omis un détail! Cette pratique était utile et nécessaire avant l'arrivée des ordinateurs qui permettent de réviser autant de fois qu'on veut le texte **AVANT** l'envoi

Comment: Cela dit, dans un mail, on peut aussi tout entièrement contester l'utilisation de la chose, et enrichir le corps du texte… Ça a déjà été soulevé ? bon, bon…

Comment: @user904 Il est vrai que l'utilisation d'un post-scriptum dans une lettre rédigée à l'ordinateur ou dans un courrier électronique peut paraître absurde. Toutefois, un certain usage récent semble s'être répandu: utiliser un post-scriptum pour parler d'un thème qui serait hors-sujet dans le corps du courrier. Une sorte de "Au fait" ou "En passant". Exemple typique: le contenu de l'email est strictement professionnel, mais comme on connaît bien la personne on rajoute: "PS: N'oublie pas l'anniversaire de XXX vendredi."

Comment: Je ne connais pas la bonne abréviation vue que je n’utilise que très rarement la chose (en fait, je n’ai pas souvenir d’avoir recouru une seule fois au post scriptum), simplement, je tenais à préciser que le correcteur orthographique de Thunderbird (Aspell je crois) est très lacunaire, aussi vous seriez très averti de ne pas y placer votre foi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans le contexte du travail j'ai pratiquement toujours vu :

- PS :
- ps :

ou

- PS.
- ps.

Je ne peux pas parler pour un consensus mais il me semble raisonnable d'utiliser PS, sans séparateur.

Answer (score 8):

D'après le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/post-scriptum) :

> POST-SCRIPTUM, subst. masc.
>
> Complément ajouté par l'auteur au bas d'une lettre, après la signature, et généralement signalé par l'abréviation P.(-)S.

On devrait donc utiliser soit *P.S.* soit *P.-S.* cette dernière abréviation étant seule signalée par le dictionnaire de l'Académie.

Comment: Ou bien décider de suivre l'usage de ses interlocuteurs sans se préoccuper de l'Académie.

Comment: @Evpok A moins d'espérer que ses interlocuteurs changent de comportement en réalisant que leur graphie est incorrecte, surtout si l'on se trouve en situation de donner le 'la'.

Comment: Plus par usage que par irrespect de l'Académie, "P.S. : " heurte moins mon œil, que le laborieux "P.-S. : ". Cependant lorsque que je ferai un envoie à l'Académie, j'ajouterai le '-' si une annotation exotique s'impose à ma missive. P.S. : Aucun courrier prévu pour le 23 quai Conti, PARIS VI°

Answer (score 5):

D'après [Antidote](http://www.druide.com/antidote.html) :

> Le postscriptum est introduit avec la forme abrégée P.-S., suivie d’un tiret.
>
> *P.-S. — Le port du casque protecteur sera obligatoire lors de la
>   visite.*
>
> Attention !
>
> 1. Chaque lettre de l’abréviation P.-S. est suivie d’un point ; les deux lettres sont séparées par un trait d’union.
> 2. L’abréviation est suivie d’un tiret, et non d’un deux-points ou d’un trait d’union.
> 3. On ne met pas plus qu’un postscriptum par lettre.

D'après [le Bon Usage](http://www.lebonusage.com/) :

> *P. S.* = *post scriptum* (comme nom, *un P.-S.*)

Comment: Hors sujet, mais je trouve la construction "On ne met pas plus qu’un postscriptum par lettre" sonne mal, j'aurais plutôt tendance à utiliser "pas plus d'un" pour un dénombrement. Pouvez-vous éclairer ma lanterne sur ce point? (C'est réellement de la curiosité, je n'y connais pas grand chose en linguistique)

Comment: Je n'ai pas vraiment trouvé de justification en dehors d'Antidote lui-même, dans un article sur l'accord de _Plus d'un_. Je cite :

Les expressions nominales formées avec _plus d’un(e)_ requièrent que le nom soit au singulier, même si, dans leur globalité, ces expressions impliquent logiquement l’idée de pluralité.

**Truc.** — Dans ces expressions, on peut remplacer _de_ par _que_. L’accord singulier avec _un(e)_ ressort alors plus clairement.

_Manuel a reçu **plus d’une critique élogieuse** (...)_
On pourrait dire : _­**plus qu’une** critique élogieuse._

Comment: @ThomasRadioyes Indice : formulation québecoise.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense aussi que le post-scriptum, n'a pas sa place dans un email. J'utilise plutôt le nota-bene N.B. qui permet d'attirer l'attention sur un point important.